# Adding Google Charts <script> to Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a Google Chart (directly, from HTML, rather than using the *Publish* option on a Chart from within Sheets. Sheet charts don't do what I need) directly into the WordPress web interface.

Unfortunately, the `<script>` has to be inserted in head to work. Any ideas?

I aim to have a unique chart on every page/post (it's a blog about star mapping, and I'm using a scatter plot as the X/Y star locations), so doing it in a template won't work.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? It might help you get a response quicker.

Comment: Sure!  Bear in mind I'm a relative code novice.  I know my way around HTML, but I'm only using the web interface for Wordpress and have been using it for less than a week now.

The code I'm using for star mapping is pretty simple, it's just the script for Google Charts.  (it's too long to post here)

 
When pasted into a HTML, the code draws the chart correctly.  However, when I try to paste the script into Wordpress, I get actual code showing up, presumably because I can't write it to head.

Comment: What other info could I supply that would help answer this? The character limit is too small for me to paste the actual code I’m attempting to use.

Comment: Here's the thing:  No one will read that amount of code. You need to narrow it down to just a few lines of problematic code. Error messages usually help provide a way to focus on the important bits. It might be less an issue with code, and more of an app -specific/UI problem. I'm not a WordPress user, but I'm sure there are many on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to understand your whole question properly. But as you mentioned, you want to add script to head then you can use below code in your theme's functions.php

```
    function hook_javascript() {
        ?>
            <script>
                alert('Page is loading...');
            </script>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'hook_javascript');
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!

If I'm using the web interface for Wordpress and I want to write a unique script in each post's head, would this work?  Where would I go to do that.

Again, apologies - code novice.

Comment: Yes, it will work. If you have java script code then use above method. If you have .js file then use wp_enqueue_script()
You need to do this change in your theme's functions.php

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Can you walk me though what your hook does so I can be sure I’m using it right?

Comment: Above code will add javasript code/file to your page. You can see in view page source.